# Restsharp SimpleAuthenticator

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm using restsharp to make rest api client. This is my code:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://url.com");
        client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("client_id", "testapi", "client_secret", "password");

        var request = new RestRequest("webapi/rest/auctions", Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("limit", "10"); 
        request.AddParameter("order", "auction_id"); 
        request.AddParameter("page", "1"); 
        request.AddParameter("offset", "0");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine("request: " + response.Content);
```

Response is always: `{"error":"unauthorized_client"}`

And  [here is information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZGPp.png) from documentation of this rest api

Comment: have you watched the request in Fiddler to validate that there's an Authorization header being put on it?

Comment: Whether your base URI is correct?